# Member struct of a class prints incorrect attribute values in main, but has the right values in memory

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

Here's the code I was playing around with to understand member types inside a class better:

```
class First
{
    struct trialStruct; //forward declaration

    public:
        First() : t {nullptr} //constructor
        {
            trialStruct temp {1,5};
            cout<<temp.a<<" "<<temp.b<<endl<<endl; //attribute values of temporary struct variable
            t = &temp;
            cout<<t->a<<" "<<t->b<<endl<<endl; //attribute values of member struct variable
        }
        trialStruct* t; //member struct attribute
    
    private:
        struct trialStruct //struct
        {
            trialStruct(int aTemp , int bTemp) : a {aTemp} , b {bTemp}
            {
                //done
            }
            int a,b;
            int sum();
        };
};

int First::trialStruct::sum() //definition of struct function
{
    return a+b;
}
int main()
{
    //initialising object, printing struct attribute's attributes
    First obj {};
    cout<<obj.t->a<<endl; 
    cout<<obj.t->b<<endl;
    cout<<obj.t->sum();
    return 0;
}
```

The outputs in the contructor give the intended value of 1 and 5 for a and b. But the output in main gives output as follows: a = 1, b = 0, return value of sum(): 0

I don't know where I'm going wrong in my understanding of how this should work.

Output Screenshot:

[image]

EDIT:John Filleu's comment clarified what I was doing wrong. The temp object is destroyed after the constructor is exited, thus giving the trialStruct pointer undefined behavior.

Comment: The temporary object `temp` is destroyed when you exit `First`'s constructor. Using its members after destruction is undefined behavior. Is there any reason `t` needs to be a `trialStruct *` and can't just be a `trialStruct`?

Comment: That makes so much sense, thank you! I made `t` a pointer because I was running into another issue where a forward declaration of `trialStruct` wasn't enough, the code gave an error of `trialStruct t` being an **incomplete type**.


EDIT: What I mentioned above is another doubt of mine. Why does the ordering of members inside a class matter for structs and other types? I have to add the definitition of `trialStruct` before the `trialStruct t` data member declaration to avoid the **incomplete type** error.

Comment: Make it a `unique_ptr<trialStruct>` then initialise it using `new` or `make_unique`. IE: `t.reset(new trialStruct(1,5));`